# MySQL get records between now and a month last year

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, timestamp

I am trying to create an SQL query to select records where the timestamp is less than NOW() but is greater than september last year, but i dont want to specify the year by putting something like:

```
date > '01/09/2014'
```

If i were to run the query today it should give me records from:

september 2014 to May 2015 (May as it is the month at the time of creating this question)

If i run it next year it should give me records from
september 2015 to May 2016 (May as it is the month at the time of creating this question)

Comment: If you know that from which month you need data why not just use as `select * from table where date_col between '2014-09-01' and curdate()`

Comment: i would but that means that next year it wont work correctly as it will still be getting records from september 2014 onwards and it will need to be september 2015 onwards.

Comment: Why not use `intval(date('Y')) -1)` to determine that string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can construct the date:

```
where date >= str_to_date(concat(year(now()) - 1, '-09-01'),
                          '%Y-%m-%d') and
      date < now()
```

I am guessing that you actually want a slightly more complicated condition.  If you run the query at the end of the year (say in December), you probably want September of the current year:

```
where date >= str_to_date(concat(year(now()) - (month(now) < 9), '-09-01'),
                          '%Y-%m-%d') and
      date < now()
```